# Drag n Drop sections on the BBC website, how is it done?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a new project to plan and the client likes the BBC's drag / drop sections on the home page. How is that done ? Is it with a framework like Sencha or jQuery ?

Thanks

Rich :)

Comment: You should provide a screenshot since the BBC layout can change in the future and so this question won't be useful anymore. Also, have you tried anything yourself? Looking into the source code for example? This question does not show any research effort. Finding out what framework was used can be easily solved by looking into the source.

Comment: link to this page please

Comment: Did you even bother to take a look at the page source?

Comment: Check the source code on the BBC home page and you'll see where the scripts come from.

Comment: The BBC uses it's own JavaScript framework called [Glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) due to them unable to find other libraries conforming to [their requirements](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/articles/what_is_glow.shtml)

Comment: i looked at the source, I was a bit baffled, but yes I see now jQuery. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BBC uses its own JavaScript framework called [Glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/). What you're looking at is probably the [sortable widget](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/api/glow.widgets.sortable.shtml).

The "Customisable Homepage Demo" at the bottom of the [sortable widget documentation](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/widgets/sortable/) looks like a barebones version of the BBC homepage.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){   
    $('.bucket').sortable({
        connectWith: '.bucket'
    });

    $('.element').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.bucket'
    });
    $('ul', 'li').disableSelection();
})
```

This allows you to have many containers, and you can drag elements between containers.

Press the '+' element to create a 'task'. Then try and drag it.
An example: http://jsfiddle.net/RD5M6/3/

For further reading: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

most likely a custom version of http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

Answer (score 0):

The BBC are most likely using their own Javascript library. Glow, as mentioned already.

But this type of interface can also be achieved with jQueryUI or Scriptaculous:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/draggable/